# R network.arrow() looks strange when curved

Tags: r, graph, plot

I'm trying to draw some appealing curved arrows on top of a map. The best looking arrows that I can find are network.arrow() from the network package. However, when I make them curved things get weird. Compare the following:

```
library(maps)
library(network)
map("usa")
network.arrow(-110,37,-85,40,length=5,width=1,angle=20)
```

[image]

```
map("usa")
network.arrow(-110,37,-85,40,length=5,width=1,angle=20,curve=2)
```

[image]

I find it difficult to believe that network.arrow() would integrate a curve option that inherently makes the arrowheads look bizarre, and yet I cant get it perform properly. How can I fix this?

Note: I am aware of great circle, and no, I'm not trying to get flight paths drawn properly. The data I am trying to visualize is on a much smaller scale than the example presented here.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is a bug

Comment: Thanks skyebend. I'll talk to the Washington U guys to confirm.